# i want to fetch data from firestore between to 2 date in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

## I have an accounting application useing flutter and firestore and I want to fetch data between two dates. I searched everywhere and could not find, but I hope that you will help me. Are there any examples of this, thanks

[firebase image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/po5TO.png)

I have uploaded a picture to my database, I rely on (invoice_date) in the filtering process

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not a code writing service but are happy to help with existing code you've attempted. It sounds like you're asking how to write a query in Firestore? If so, the Firestore documentation is pretty good - see [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) and then the [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter.dev) is an additional resource. Take a look at those, write some code and post it when you get stuck!